# What do I lose when serving time in jail?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When you serve your time in Jail, do you lose stats like in Oblivion? Also, can you get your stuff from the chest back after serving your time without having to sneak in and steal it?

What negative effects has serving out your sentence in jail?

Comment: Welcome to Gaming.SE!  You should split this into two separate questions.  Make sure to check and see if someone else has already asked.

Comment: Hi Kyo, as OrigamiRobot said you should only ask one question at a time, I have edited your question to be only about the jail, as that was already answered. For the question about Vilkas, please just ask a second question and I'm sure you'll get an answer here.

Comment: Dropping your soap in the shower may have a negative effect.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you serve time in Jail you can (depending on the time you serve) lose some or all of your experience towards the next skill level.

You don't lose whole skill levels.

So if you're, say, level 49 and one strike (or pickpocket or spell,etc.) away from level 50 you'll get bumped back down to the start of level 49 for that skill. Got it?

Comment: Do the thief-related spells (pickpocket, sneak) still increase instead of decrease in jail?

Comment: Spells? They're skills. And I don't think they do, but don't quote me.

Comment: So you don't lose your items then?

Comment: @bob you don't lose your items, only stolen ones.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on how much time you spend in jail is the amount that gets taken off your skill level.