# Do stolen quest items stay in inventory after being caught by guards?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I have small bounties in a few places in Skyrim that I wanted to pay off. I was dumping off all my stolen items beforehand and I realize that I have a stolen quest item, that I obviously can't take out of my pockets. I hadn't really planned on doing this quest for awhile, but I want my bounties gone. This got me thinking...do stolen **quest** items stay with you after getting caught by guards? Or will I lose it? (presuming that the item is returned to where I stole it, or does it end up somewhere else?)

Comment: Near duplicate, corroborating Kevin's answer: [Do I lose quest items in jail?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/130463/do-i-lose-quest-items-in-jail)

Answer (score 3):

Quest items you stole will be given back to you/kept. If you go in jail you will get them once you escape. If you open the chest with your other belongings you will also find them there. The same goes for when paying bounties.